# Crystal reports 10 (VS2008) - SDF database

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, sdf

I'm working with an old software developed in VS2008. 
The application also uses Crystal Reports 10/10.5 and a SQL .sdf database.
I need to modify the .rpt form template and I'm having problems to load the (local) .sdf file in Crystal Reports: in the standalone application and also in the integrated environment in VS2008

I googled for similar problems so I ended up to recreate the same 32bit environment with Windows XP-SP3, VS2008, Crystal Reports 10 (standalone), SQL Compact Edition 3.5, Crystal Reports 10.5 run-time for VS2008.

In the "Server Explorer" section, I'm able to load the .sdf file:
[Server Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Puhz8.png)

But when I switch to the "Field Explorer", I don't see any option that allows me to load the sdf file to be used with .the rpt form:
[Field Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emps4.png)

I tried every other option in the list (ODBC, OLE DB..), but no luck. I also installed SQL Server 2005, no luck either.
I also tried to work in Crystal Reports 10 standalone application, same problems.

How can I load a sdf file in the "Database Fields" in Crystal reports?